# Can 'ps' show me only processes I own, plus all their ancestors, in tree format?

Tags: ps

Here's what I want to do: I want to get a tree-formatted list of processes from **ps** (as when you do `ps auxwwf`), but only of processes that are either owned by me, or are ancestors of processes owned by me.  So if I own a **bash** process way down the tree, and it has ancestors owned by root, I want to see those root ancestors in addition to the ones I own.  I do **not** want to see any process trees that do not contain any processes owned by me.

Is there any way to do this with **ps**'s normal options, or do I need to write a script to parse the output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This won't be very fast, but it seems to do the trick:

```
# Bash, GNU ps
pidchain ()
{
    if [[ -z $1 ]]; then
        return;
    fi;
    if (( $1 == 0 )); then
        return;
    else
        echo "$1";
        pidchain $(ps -p $1 o ppid=);
    fi
}

pids () {
    ps o pid= -u $1 |
        while read pid
        do
            pidchain $pid
        done |
            sort -nu
}

ps uxwwf -p $(pids username)
```

Comment: Close enough; this inspired me to write my own (faster ;-)) version in PHP.

Comment: @dirtside: Would you post your code as an answer? I actually looked at the source of `pstree` as a potential starting point (and probably would need to look at `pgrep` as well), but that project will have to take a number and wait in line.

Answer (score 3):

Try `ps -ejH` that displays a tree of processes, based of father-sons links.

**edit**

To see only *your* processes

```
  ps -fjH -u myname
```

Comment: That shows processes the OP wants excluded.

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: That omits processes the OP wants shown.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson Well..

Answer (score 0):

This depends on your os, but based on the ps command you gave I think this might work:

`ps --user dirtside -uxxf`

Comment: That doesn't show processes the OP wants included.

Answer (score 0):

My take on this, using iteration instead of recursion (no worry that you'll overflow your stack):

[ps_backtrace.sh](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1AjwmWfE0OMoaoEDh3PuCXjZgLMchkfGiIoxBEieDRio/edit#heading=h.vz0662mnm51u)